# Set roles in Jersey web service

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, dropwizard

I am creating a web service using Jersey + Jetty + Dropwizard + Hibernate.

Let's say I got a web resource like this:

```
@Path("/")
@PermitAll
public class Resource {
    @RolesAllowed("user")
    @GET
    public String get() { return "GET"; }


@RolesAllowed("admin")
@POST
public String post(String content) { return content; }

@Path("sub")
public SubResource getSubResource() {
    return new SubResource();
}
}
```

I know you can check a user's role with `HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole`.

The question is, how do I assign the roles to begin with? How does Jersey knows what to return for the `isUserInRole` method or knows how to filter people from not getting to specific resources based on their roles?

I do not have a `web.xml` or a `webdefault.xml` so the definitions should be done somewhere else.

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for [Dropwizard Auth](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.0/docs/manual/auth.html)? It has support for Basic and OAuth. And there's a third party [lib for JWT](https://github.com/ToastShaman/dropwizard-auth-jwt). All that role stuff is handled by the framework. Unless you have and none of those solutions worked for you and you want whip up your own

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a provider class which supports the @RolesAllowed("admin") annotation and then you have to register the provider class in your application .Normally it is done in web.xml but as you are not using it,you have to provide it on your own.The related example could be find [here](http://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jersey-rest-security/)

Comment: this example includes making settings in the web.xml file which I stated I do not have

Comment: How are you loading your jersey servlet then . You must be using some configuration file or annotaion(@webservlet ).You have to load it there.

Comment: I got a config.yml file and all configuration of resources etc. are done with dropwizard's configuration class

Comment: Or more accurately, a dropwizard's application class which is initialized with a configuration object

Answer (score 0):

Jersey uses its own mechanism to check roles (see `SecurityContext` interface), however if it is not explicitly set, it falls back to container authentication, which is usually implemented using JaaS. If you had `web.xml` you would be able to configure basics of it there.

Then again frequently authentication is done differently. If you can log user in manually, for instance have a service that can check name/password, then you could implement a `ContainerRequestFilter` that would fill security context which would make `@RolesAllowed` annotation to just work.

For instance:

**Updated based on comments**

Resouce method logs in user:

```
@Path("some/login/path")
public void login() {
    String name = getUsernameFromRequest();
    String password = // like above
    User user = loginService.login(name, password);
    request.getSession().addAttribute("user", user);
}
```

Initialize security context in filter for all requests.

```
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class JerseySecurityContextFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext context) throws IOException {
    User user = getUserFromSession();
    if (user != null) {
         // this sets security context for the rest of processing
         // it should make @RolesAllowed work
         context.setSecurityContext(new JerseySecurityContext(user);
    }
}

final class JerseySecurityContext implements SecurityContext {

    private final User user;

    public JerseySecurityContext(final User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public boolean isUserInRole(final String roleName) {
        return user.hasRole(roleName);
    }

    public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
        return new Principal() {
            public String getName() {
                return user.getName();
            }
        };
    }

    public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

If you would rather use JaaS then you would have to configure security in your application configuration. These are some examples for embedded [Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/embedded-examples.html).

Comment: Right now I got a resource method named loginUser which gets the user name and password and check if it matches the one in the db. How do I tell this JerseySecurityContextFilter to run when this specific resource class is called?

Comment: When user logs in and your resource method is run create a session and put the user into it. Then the filter will be able to check if the user exists in a session. If yes, he is logged in, if not he isn't. You can add the filter to jersey using a couple of methods. One of them is registering filter class with the `ResourceConfig`.

Comment: I now realized that I misled you a bit by suggesting to log user in in the filter. That would be fine, if you used something like Basic Auth. If you use a dedicated form or something similar backed by a resource with login method, put user object into session there and just pull it out of the session in the filter. The rest can remain the same. I can update the code sample if you wish.